# Resizing dataURL with Javascript canvas not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have done lots of research, and i'v become completely stumped on this issue.

The code is supposed to resize the dataURL to 500x500px. However, it ends up with a blank image.

The original dataURL variable at the top of the code IS valid. I console.log it, and it works when opening it in the browser. So I don't think that's the issue.

```
$('#img-resizer .do-it').bindFirst("click", function () {
        originalImg = $("#img-resizer img.original").cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL('image/jpeg');

        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = originalImg;

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = 500;
        canvas.height = 500;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.width = 500;
        ctx.height = 500;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 500, 500);

        cropImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        $($("#img-resizer").attr("save-to")).attr("src", cropImg);
    });
```

So what ends up happening, is the cropImg variable is just a blank image when opened in my browser.

As I said earlier, I am positive that the originalImg variable is valid, as I console.log it and it works when opened.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `load` event. **very important**

remove unnecessary `ctx.width/height`

```
$('#img-resizer .do-it').bindFirst("click", function() {
  originalImg = $("#img-resizer img.original").cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL('image/jpeg');

  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 500;
    canvas.height = 500;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 500, 500);
    var cropImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    $($("#img-resizer").attr("save-to")).attr("src", cropImg);
  }
  img.src = originalImg;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate the help GREATLY!

Comment: A pleasure to help you